# Is it possible to add a redirect in AWS S3 signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Javascript SDK to generate a signed URL for uploading via PUT. I've tried adding `WebsiteRedirectLocation` which generates extra parameters `%3Bx-amz-website-redirect-location&x-amz-website-redirect-location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"` in the URL. But S3 only returns a 200 response.

```js
const params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket_name',
    Key: 'key_name',
    WebsiteRedirectLocation: 'http://www.google.com'
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const signedURL = await (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } 
            else {
                resolve(data);
            }
         });
    }));
    return signedURL;
};
```

Comment: What are you actually wanting this to do?  Redirect the browser immediately after the file is uploaded? Or something else?

Comment: I want to make a redirect to my API endpoint. It does some processing on the uploaded file. Why I don't use API gateway for the upload is explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996271/7721443). I want to reduce the number of API calls made by customers (running an API as a service).

Comment: @real_shardul did you find an answer if it's possible to do a redirect?

Comment: @ciekawy I didn't. Stopped working on this project long ago.